# How to build a LGA1150 HTPC with HDMI CEC support?

Tags: hdmi, htpc, haswell

**Story:** I decided to build myself powerful HTPC using top modern "bleeding-edge" hardware, I mean LGA1150 with Haswell (Desktop 4th Generation Intel Core Processor Family). And because an easy way of remote controlling is very important to me, I'm interested in HDMI CEC support and using just one remote for controlling the TV/projector and the HTPC.

**Goal:** The simplest theoretical way to do that is find LGA1150 motherboard with integrated HDMI CEC support, unlike some Intel LGA1155 (H61, H77) boards which requires additional header to be connected ([Pulse-Eight headers](http://www.pulse-eight.com/store/products/117-internal-hdmi-cec-adapter.aspx)).

**Problem:** Google does not help you much nowadays. So which board supports HDMI CEC? How to realize this? Keep reeding...

*Note: since I'm not oriented to AMD, this is just research about Intel's CPU and desktop boards.*

Comment: I haven't enough of reputation to add HDMI-CEC flag, please someone with 300+ reputation, try to consider adding this new flag. Thanks

Comment: It is ok to ask and answer your own question.  Could you state the title of this in the form of a question.

Comment: @StBlade Sure, but plese recommend some terms. "[self-answered]" ... or how? Thanks for correcting my typos. :)

Comment: How to build a LGA 1150 HTPC with HDMI CEC support?

Comment: @Journeyman Geek ... Putting this 3,5y old question on hold?!

Comment: Yeah, We should have been quicker - sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resolute finding:**

Intel Haswell processors has no HDMI CEC support as you can find in [this 4th gen. Core CPU datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/4th-gen-core-family-desktop-vol-1-datasheet.pdf).

**So there are three ways out:**

1. Build the HTPC with older hardware (LGA1155) and use [HTPC header](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-033841.htm).
2. Use USB-CEC adapter (for example [this one from Pulse-Eight](http://www.pulse-eight.com/store/products/104-usb-hdmi-cec-adapter.aspx)).
3. Forgot about just one remote (it's ok with projectors but not with TV) and use special case with remote or use CIR solution.

If someone is interested in the components:

**Chosen hardware specification**
(it may vary depending on the availability on the market):

- CPU: [Core i5-4570T](http://ark.intel.com/products/75045) or [Core i3-4330T](http://ark.intel.com/products/77770/) (max. DTP 35W both)
- MOBO with [H87 chipset](http://ark.intel.com/products/75004):

  - ASRock [H87M PRO4](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H87M%20Pro4/?cat=Specifications)
  - or Intel [DH87RL](http://ark.intel.com/products/69044) (but it's a brother of DH87MC which I own and which is very bad board)
- RAM: [KHX16C9K2/16X](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/partsinfo.asp?ktcpartno=KHX16C9K2/16X) (or another tested/compatibile with selected mobo and CPU)
- CASE: SilverStone [Lascala SST-LC16B-M](http://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=81) with remote and iMon VFD (i choose option 3)
- other stuff (Fortron Aurum Xilenser 400, Coolermaster GeminII M4, Enermax UCTB8P fans, Blue-Ray drive and some of my 3,5" HDDs)

**Chosen software:**

- [LibreELEC](http://libreelec.tv/) media center - it's XMBC appliance, which I'd like very much (instead of classic XMBC distributions)

Answer (score 1):

The latest [**Intel NUC**'s have HDMI CEC support](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/intel-nuc-kits/000023500.html):

1. Onboard support (for power on/off only)

[image: Intel NUC HDMI CEC BIOS configuration]

2. And a header in case you want to do more via Kodi, for example with an [adapter](http://www.gorite.com/intel-nuc-products/hdmi-cec-adapters):

[image: Intel NUC CEC header]

You can also back-port HDMI CEC to *any PC* (not only NUC) using [this adapter](https://www.pulse-eight.com/p/104/usb-hdmi-cec-adapter).

Comment: thanks for the NUC update, btw. the Intel's headers and the Pulse-Eight adapter has been already mentioned in my original answer. :)

Answer (score -2):

Break free from hardware specific solution and get a Harmony Remote. This enables you to pick an IR receiver of your choice. If you only have only two components might be overkill.

I used a USB IR receiver from eBay and control Kodi, Media portal etc using Harmony Remote which also does my TV and amp.

**Rationale**
If aim is to control both devices then you don't need to restrict yourself to CEC. You could use this alternate approach.

Comment: At least say why the down vote. I was encouraging an alternate line of thinking. If intent is to operate projector and PC using a single remote then you don't have to use CEC.

Comment: Imo this is not *"LGA1150 HTPC with HDMI CEC support"* solution, so I'm not considering this as a qualified answer. Maybe you should explain the HDMCI CEC background first and your solution as a conclusion if in your opinion is CEC something like a "wrong way". Anyway this is very good tip for a separate topic such as *"How to control multiple devices with one remote"*.

Comment: It's not hardware-specific though. They're discussing using/implementing the HDMI-CEC standard